# Why does using SCP return an error "No such file or directory"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I am using this command because i want to transfer a whole directory from my local machine to an Amazon VM

```
sudo scp -i testing2.pem -r ubuntu@########:/Users/MyComputer/Desktop/citylife /home/ubuntu
```

But the error returning each time is

```
scp: /Users/MyComputer/Desktop/citylife: No such file or directory
```

The directory exists and is correct but i can not work out this error

Comment: Do you have the source and destination reversed?: sudo scp -i testing2.pem -r /Users/MyComputer/Desktop/citylife ubuntu@########:/home/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using seems to be not correct. Try this:

`sudo scp -r -i testing2.pem /Users/MyComputer/Desktop/citylife ubuntu@########:/home/ubuntu`